# Can we have dates in the profile answer tab?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, answers, profile-page

In a profile's **questions tab** I see a username and date for every question.

[image: Questions]

Can we please have the same for the **answers tab**?

From time to time I check the answers I gave that day and have to open them to see when I answered. There is a lot of space for more information. Maybe there is other useful data to display.

[image: Answers]

Comment: I would love to have this added to the profile page, it drives me crazy that I have to go into the answer to figure out the date.

Comment: Yes, please.  It's also a good way to see quickly how active other users are.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This will show up in the next build.

Comment: When is the next build scheduled?

Comment: Well, it's live now and brought to life [nasty little bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184079/152859).

Comment: Maybe you can consider capitalizing the months as well?

Comment: @Antony Probably not.  This is consistent with our display of time in other parts of the application (specifically, the questions tab in the user profile).

Comment: @BenCollins but it is inconsistent with other parts of the site, such as the timestamp below the actual answers. Just pointing that out.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII you're not wrong, but no matter how I do it, it will be different than someone else's preferences and different than the way dates are rendered somewhere else.  In this case I think it makes the most sense to match the way dates are rendered for answers on the answers tab.

Comment: @BenCollins: Shouldn't this be tagged [status-completed] now?

Comment: @juergend yep.  I keep a list of stuff I did going into a pending build, and I generally try to watch when builds go out so I can go verify the changes did what I expected them to do in production and then update tags accordingly.  Sometimes I miss it.  Thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 13):

#### Notice: This feature has been officially rolled out, and so this user-script is no longer necessary. It shall remain here, though, for reputation's sake :)

I liked this idea so much, so I created a user script to do it:

[SOAnswerDate - answer dates in user profiles!](https://stackapps.com/questions/4145/soanswerdate-answer-dates-in-user-profiles)

[image]

Comment: +1 for a temporary solution but I still think this should be implemented without the need of a user script. :)

Comment: FWIW I changed the return to `return date.toISOString().substring(0,10);` to just show `yyyy-mm-dd`. Thanks again.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I was simply using the format respected on the answer page for consistency, but I could see how that would be better.

Comment: @Richard yes sorry, I should have qualified: to match *my* preferences. Actually now I'm going to look into using a UserScript to format everything my way. :-)

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII for the record, it's super helpful when users so clearly demonstrate what they're requesting.  Makes my job a lot easier.

Comment: @BenCollins no problem, happy to help! Excited to see this feature officially rolled out

Answer (score 11):

Absolutely agreed, there is a lot of space for this information on the Profile > Answers tab. To minimize the visual space required and complexity of implementation, it doesn't need to include timestamp, the mouseover, relativity to current date, localization of the date, tags from the question, and all that other stuff that we show in some cases (e.g. on Profile > Questions). For me just the date in `yyyy-mm-dd` format or something would be sufficient.

Oh and if we don't want to take up visual display space (for those cases where people write [ridiculously stupid long-ass titles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52711/what-factors-could-cause-the-following-sqlexception-a-transport-level-error-has)) then the date of the post could be exposed as a hover/mouseover attribute for the title (currently there is no tooltip when mousing over the title, so we wouldn't be usurping other content currently being shown).

It would also be nice to show the same tooltip on mouseover in the Summary Tab > Answers area, which does *not* have the display area to show the date front and center, so in fact this might be the most consistent way to expose the information.

As an added bonus, we could also show the date of last edit.