# Timestamp in the flagging summary page comes twice

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, timestamps, flag-history

I just noted that the timestamp of post in the flag page (flagging summary) comes twice like this:

> [image]

As noted by [@bluefeet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184079/timestamp-in-the-flagging-summary-page-comes-twice?noredirect=1#comment-562264) it is related to [this request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145289/can-we-have-dates-in-the-profile-answer-tab), Here is the reason why it is related to that feature request (noted by [@Azik](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184079/timestamp-in-the-flagging-summary-page-comes-twice?noredirect=1#comment-562285)):

The issue is only with answer. Timestamp on flagged questions seems to be fine:

> [image]

Can we fix this?

Comment: I wonder if it is related to [this request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145289/can-we-have-dates-in-the-profile-answer-tab). The time is now appearing on the answers summary page but the time is showing twice for flags.

Comment: @bluefeet yep, you win some you lose some. Probably the dev working on that (Oded?! ;)) didn't think to check that page while unit testing. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - May be [Ben Collins](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/145289/revisions) ??

Comment: @hims056 hmm... it's so much easier to blame Oded! :-P

Comment: issue is only on flags to answers, flags on questions seems to be fine

Comment: @Azik - Yeah correct. And that prove bluefeet's comment is correct. Edited. :)

Comment: Yep, it was me.  I'm on it.

Comment: It looks like this has been fixed.

Comment: @bluefeet - Yes you are correct. Thanks.