# Suggested edit times are skewiff

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, suggested-edits, design

The times that a suggested edit was suggested and the post was posted don't line up in the suggested edit view.

> [image]

I've observed this behaviour on both MSO and SO, but can't see it in any other queues.

I'm using Chrome 27.0.1453.110 m on Windows 7 if it's relevant.

Comment: Yeah, there's a random `float: right` on there for some reason.

Comment: Confirmed Firefox 21 on linux

Comment: @Tim not random, it was introduced [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/145289/152859). :)

Comment: What's skewiff, a typo? Skewed?

Comment: It means "not straight" or "lopsided" @chuex, it's not a typo. [Wiktionary has it](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/skewiff) as an alternate spelling of skew-whiff but I disagree with that. I've never seen it written as a two word hyphenate.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards - interesting, dictionary.com doesn't have it at all. I guess I learned something.

Comment: It does, it looks like dictonary.com agrees with Wiktionary @chuex: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/skew-whiff *sigh*, it appears the wider world doesn't understand that we spell these words 5 or 6 different ways and they're all correct because no one remembers (or can work out) how they actually came into being :-).

Comment: +1 just for using _skewiff_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.

Comment: Cheers! Can you please mark [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184390/152859) too as completed? :)