# Timestamp in the suggested edits review page is going out of it's boundary

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, suggested-edits, design

Timestamp in the [suggested edits review page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2313669) is going out of it's boundary.

> [image: Incorrect]

AFAIK, the suggested edits timestamp was near to it's type (i.e. asked, proposed) like this:

> [image: Correct]

Checked on Chrome (27.0.1453.110 m), Firefox (21.0) on Windows XP

The issue is in other Stack Exchange sites as well. E.g. Have a look at [this suggested edit](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/17486) on Physics.SE. Also in [Beta sites.](https://sports.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1220)

Can we fix this?

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards - Exact duplicate. I couldn't find it. But at present it has a bounty. So...

Comment: @Nick - Also retag [this duplicate bug report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/187352/187824) as status-completed. :)