# Why do you show Moderator's review count even when there is not flags to review?

Tags: bug, status-completed, 10k-tools, top-bar

For last two days I see *random* moderator's flags review count at top bar:

> [image]

When refresh the page it shows some numbers. When I click on that number it redirects me to Tools -> flags. But I don't see any pending flags there.

> [image]

Is this a bug or I am missing something?

Notes:

- There is no userscript running in my browser for flags like [SO flags in Toolbar](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/87488).
- I also see this from my Android mobile (Fullsite view)

Comment: [It just happened again!](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Rgpcp.png) after opening [this latest question.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/187351/187824)

Comment: And it'll keep on happening until it is fixed...