# Flag count at the top toolbar is significantly higher than what I actually see in the 10k tools page

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, 10k-tools

I've noticed that all the close flags were moved to the close queue. Well done! It's a huge step forward!

But now I've noticed something weird. The flag count at the top toolbar is inconsistent with the number of flags I can actually see (significantly).

For example, [image: I can see 259 flags at the top flag bar] But [image: only 62 flags in the 10k tools]

Does this qualify as a bug? I mean, I bet some of those attributes to comment flags, but a full 200 flags? Which I can't even handle? I don't think that's right.

Comment: Also http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/187352/187824

Comment: Both of these are slightly different. For once, there is no sufficient answer or explanation on neither. Second, I've only noticed this magnitude of difference since the latest flag change.

Comment: The only different on these questions is that both duplicate questions were noticed on Meta (where actual flags are rare or mostly 0).

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: It's a pity that we don't yet have an explanation; the dev team is probably enjoying some summer time off (4th of July on a Thursday is an excellent opportunity to create a long weekend). But it is most likely the same bug.