# Activity sort on answers tab shows creation date, not last activity date

Tags: bug, profile-page, timestamps

Not that long ago, [dates were added to the answers tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145289/can-we-have-dates-in-the-profile-answer-tab), which was helpful. However, sorting by activity shows the answer *creation* date, not the actual activity date. This causes the dates displayed to be inconsistent with the date-based sort order:

[image: answers sorted by activity showing creation date]

The activity date should be shown for this view, like it is for the same sort option on the questions tab.

Comment: Just noticed this now myself and was about to report. :)