# Manual "Possible duplicate of" comments are wrongly removed when question is closed

Tags: discussion, feature-request, duplicate-questions

When closing a question as duplicate the "Possible duplicate of" comment is automagically added to the question.

However when adding such a comment manually: "possible duplicate of random text" that comment is also removed. To me it doesn't make sense that questions which to not point to a SO / SE question or even comments without any links in it are also removed when the question is closed as a dupe.

I just found this out by close voting a question as a dupe of another question, but I also added a manual comment which linked to a user profile (because it contains lots of relevant information for OP and possible future reasons):

```
possible duplicate of this [user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/727208/teresko?tab=answers&sort=votes)'s list.
```

By the looks of it the script simply checks whether the comment starts with "possible duplicate of" and if it matches it will be removed.

The [room 11](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php) team also did a quick test with a very simple example which also got thrown away:

```
possible duplicate of testing........
```

I understand that this issue is minor and there might as well be a technical reason for this (i.e. not having to keep track of automatic vs manual comments), but this behavior is kinda odd to me.

I can think of two solutions for this:

1. keep track of manually vs automagically added dupe comments (again you SO people might have a good reason to not want this).
2. Improve the "dupe comment matcher ™" to at least check whether the comment is in the correct format for "auto dupe comments ™" with a proper link to a question page.

Comment: Tz, tz, that happens when you make jokes out of the pre-made tests for auto-comments :)

Comment: Duplicate as well! (so this comment will also be removed ;))

Comment: Related: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/13723470#13723470

Comment: @ShadowWizard It's a similar feature request, but not a duplicate, I'd say. The one you link to has more specific boundaries on what the system chooses to delete.

Comment: @random Any chance we could get some fix for this instead of closing this question and letting the discussion die again? Or perhaps some answer on the dupe?

Comment: Also related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/47446/205842

Comment: @PeeHaa random can't fix this even if he want, he's not a dev. Anyway the issue of both is the same: auto deletion is too aggressive. Looks like it's case sensitive though, comment with "Duplicate" is not deleted. :)

Comment: That it's been reported in various ways means either a fix is upcoming or a fix is not upcoming

Comment: I know random isn't a dev, but it just sucks having questions like those hanging around without any conclusion from SO. Hell even a [status-by-design] would do.

Comment: @random exactly my point. So it would be very nice to at least know whether it is coming or not.

Comment: How about this then http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46799/automatic-possible-duplicate-links-are-removed-even-if-the-question-isnt-clos where it may be bydesign if we're taking any stock of it

Comment: That's about something else.

Comment: By "something else" it's a result of that. All duplicate closes will now wipe out all comments mentioning duplicates because acid.

Comment: Yes it's a result of that and my proposal and the dupe's proposal is about fixing that.

Comment: If you retag it with **winterbash-2013** they'll be looking at it in no time. No dev has left a comment on any of the others really.

Comment: ok ok. Even though I still think this sucks as well as the fact that I hate hats that one made me smile.

Comment: There are other bugs lying around without getting dev attention which bugs me even more, e.g. [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/191873/152859) - small bug, simple issue, tried everything in the book including bounty, no response. So guess we just have to live with that. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yeah I know that's why I often just don't bother posting feature requests anymore :P

Comment: @PeeHaa not talking about feature requests, only bugs - some minor and some pretty big but many end up getting buried.

Comment: Yeah sorry meant that too. I feel your pain :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of This is just a test comment :)